# Built in kfold function with class weights, early stop, callbacks

Tags: machine-learning

I have some problems at implementing kfold for sentiment analysis,I have used kfold with for-loop technique but ı get smallest accuracy first fold whenever run my code .After first fold val_accuracy always increase.
There is a 10% gap between first fold val_accuracy and the other folds val_accuracy(like75-85), somebody in here advised me using built in cross_val_score instead of using loop , but this function doesnt have earlystop, callbacks etc, is there any way using cross_val_score with them?

here is related part

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5,shuffle=True,random_state=7)
###skf.get_n_splits(X, y)
scores=[]

for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(skf.split(X, y.argmax(1))):
X_train_skf, X_test_skf = X[train_index], X[test_index]
y_train_skf, y_test_skf = y[train_index], y[test_index]

```
    class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(np.argmax(y_train_skf, 1)), np.argmax(y_train_skf, 1))
    class_weights = {i : class_weights[i] for i in range(3)}
    print(class_weights)

    model.fit(np.array(X_train_skf), np.array(y_train_skf),
                epochs=2000,
                validation_data=(X_test_skf,y_test_skf),
                batch_size=256,
                verbose=1,
                class_weight=class_weights,
                callbacks = [es,lr_sched])
   
    y_true, y_pred = np.argmax(y_test_skf, 1), np.argmax(model.predict(X_test_skf), 1)
    print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, digits=3))
          
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
    scores.append(accuracy)
```